# Best practice for adding a non standard view and controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, routes, ruby-2.0

My situation I have a "Parent" model and controller.  I want to know the best practice for adding independent pages such as a dashboard for users.  My thought is that I can create a view `dashboard.html.erb` and inside the parent controller create a method of:

Parent controller

```
def dashboard 
end
```

Routes.rb

```
get 'parents/dashboard'
```

I've done this once and it worked fine, but is was for a 'child' model.

When I run this same situation in the parent model I get the error

*ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ParentsController#show*

*Couldn't find Parent with 'id'=dashboard*

**1.)** All I've done is add a view, added the **dashboard model** to the controller, and placed `get 'parents/dashboard'` into the **routes.rb** and it tries to reference the **show method**???  Why?

**2.)** And is this the wrong way to add pages/actions to a rails application?

Comment: I would generate a dashboard controller

Comment: I guess that's faster.  New enough that I was not sure if too many controllers would slow down the application a lot

Comment: All of the rails apps with dashboards I've worked on have a dashboard controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :parents do
   get :dashboard, on: :collection #-> url.com/parents/dashboard
end
```

---

> And is this the wrong way to add pages/actions to a rails application?

It's not *"wrong"*, it's just ineffective, as demonstrated by your problem.

The problem you have is you've included your custom route *below* the `resources :parents` route. Because [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) creates a `/:id` url which captures any requests sent to `parents/:id`, your "dashboard" request is being sent to the `show` action of the parents controller:

[image]

There are two remedies to your issue:

1. Put `get 'parents/dashboard'` *above* the `resources :parents` directive
2. Include an [additional route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) to `resources :parents` (above)

You must remember that Rails *matches* your request with a route. That means the first route to match your request is processed.

So if you have...

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :parents
get "parents/dashboard"
```

... Rails will assume the `dashboard` is the `:id` in `url.com/parents/:id`, thus sending the request to `show`.

Apart from the very top code (the recommended answer), you *could* have the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "parents/dashboard", to: :dashboard
resources :parents
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an additional route with an `:id` then the syntax is different.

```
get 'parent_dashboard/:id', to: 'parents#dashboard'
```

Notice that the person string after get. This is used as the address of the website, when the user hits this, it would go to `localhost:3000/parent_dashboard/1` if it is the first dashboard. You can exclude `:id` if you'd like. Of course, this would be different from the use case.

The second part of the route syntax is the `:to`, this method tells your app which controller and method to look at.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new view to the parents folder. Just do this:

```
parents_controller.rb

def dashboard
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
end

routes.rb
get '/parents/:id/dashboard', to: 'parents#dashboard', as: :parents_dashboards
resources :parents
```

Then in your `parents/dashboard.html.erb` view you can do everything that you can do in the parents/show view.

The link to your dashboard view would be `parents_dashboards_path` and you might have to use `parents_dashboards_path(@parent)` or `parents_dashboards_path(parent)` in certain circumstances.

This is an example of a custom path that works without using nested resources to accomplish access to the parent's dashboard.

I am using this approach in a project so I would like to hear any critique or comments on this approach. PEACE I'M OUTTA HERE!